# How to add a icon to cesium map instead of point

Tags: javascript, html, cesiumjs

I want to add icon to a cesium map intead drawing a point.
Currently I doing the below code, but want to replace the point below with an actual icon. I have been looking through the cesium documentation and cannot find anything that will do this. Thanks for any suggestions

```
var points = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.PointPrimitiveCollection());

points.add({
    position : new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude),
    color : colorDot,
    outlineColor : Cesium.Color.WHITE,
    outlineWidth : width
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cesium, this is called a billboard.  They are created in basically the same way as a point, except the image is generally loaded from a URL.

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/BillboardCollection.html

```
// Create a billboard collection with two billboards
var billboards = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.BillboardCollection());
billboards.add({
  position : new Cesium.Cartesian3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0),
  image : 'url/to/image'
});
billboards.add({
  position : new Cesium.Cartesian3(4.0, 5.0, 6.0),
  image : 'url/to/another/image'
});
```

Comment: I tried the above code and tried a URL that was a local file and I got an error cant' load local file

Comment: Web browsers don't allow JavaScript to read local files, for good reason.  Your image needs to be hosted, either on the same server that hosts your copy of Cesium, or on a server that has [enabled CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) to permit JavaScript from other sites to request assets.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @paraquat's correct answer about Billboards:  Cesium includes a "Pin Builder" that can be used to make typical map icons as billboards.  [Here's a demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Map%20Pins.html&label=Showcases).

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var pinBuilder = new Cesium.PinBuilder();

var url = Cesium.buildModuleUrl('Assets/Textures/maki/grocery.png');
var groceryPin = Cesium.when(pinBuilder.fromUrl(url, Cesium.Color.GREEN, 48), function(canvas) {
    return viewer.entities.add({
        name : 'Grocery store',
        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1705217, 39.921786),
        billboard : {
            image : canvas.toDataURL(),
            verticalOrigin : Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM
        }
    });
});
```